# Issue updating Logzio.DotNet.Log4net nuget package to latest version 1.0.12

Tags: asp.net-core

The latest version 1.0.12 of Logzio.DotNet.Log4net nuget package has an issue, when you try to add a logzio appender . It reports an error as below:

```
log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [LogzioAppender] of type [Logzio.DotNet.Log4net.LogzioAppender, Logzio.DotNet.Log4net]. Reported error follows.
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Logzio.DotNet.Core.Shipping.BulkSenderOptions.get_JsonKeysCamelCase()'.
   at Logzio.DotNet.Log4net.LogzioAppender.ActivateOptions()
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(XmlElement appenderElement)
log4net:ERROR Appender named [LogzioAppender] not found.
```

The same code works fine on previous version 1.0.11

Comment: The [link](https://github.com/logzio/logzio-logback-appender) shows 1.0.12 only adds Marker support.Can you share your code?

Comment: Hi @YiyiYou, here is the appender section of the code:


<appender name="LogzioAppender" type="Logzio.DotNet.Log4net.LogzioAppender, Logzio.DotNet.Log4net">
    <token>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</token>
    <type>IS4</type>
    <listenerUrl>https://listener.logz.io:8071</listenerUrl>
    <bufferSize>100</bufferSize>
    <bufferTimeout>00:00:05</bufferTimeout>
    <retriesMaxAttempts>3</retriesMaxAttempts>
    <retriesInterval>00:00:02</retriesInterval>
    <debug>true</debug>
    <customField>
      <key>Env</key>
      <value>UAT</value>
    </customField>
</appender>